# How to implement a modifiable queue?

Tags: c#, data-structures, queue

I have a need for a very specialized Data Structure based on a queue. My thoughts are that I am going to need to bake something myself but I would like to solicit ideas from the community before embarking.

What I need is a primarily a queue where each queue item is added by a producer. The work to be done on the queue items must be synchronous (only one item is allowed to be worked on at a time). However, the items are temporal. When a producer goes to add work to the queue, if the queue already has work added by that producer, the queue item expires and instead of removing it from the queue, the item is replaced with the producers new item as I do not want that producer to lose their position in the queue.

So the rules of the queue are:

1. Items being pulled from the queue are one at a time. This is simple enough, it is a queue after all...
2. Items can be added to the queue by multiple producers simultaneously.
3. If a producer already has an item in the queue, the queue item is replaced with the producers new item.
4. Items cannot be pulled from the queue while an item is being added to the queue (this is so that items that are being modified cannot be pulled until they are modified)
5. Producers do not necessarily need to have items in the queue, each producer can go extended periods of time with no work to be done.

Any ideas on how such a structure could be implemented or of an existing data structure that fits the need would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might want to implement [`IProducerConsumerCollection(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147.aspx). that way you can use a [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) to handle the `Add` and `Remove` operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the [BlockingCollection<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). It allows one thread to pull items one at a time using the [GetConsumingEnumerable Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx), and multiple producers to add items using the [Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287137.aspx).
2. When a producer produces a new item, do not add the item to the queue, but the producer itself. Let the producer remember the last item it produced. If the producer is already in th queue, do not add it a second time.
3. The consumer dequeues the producer and asks it for the last item in produced. If the producer produced multiple items in the meantime, it will have remembered only the last one and all previous ones will be skipped.